# Comprehensive Salesforce Marketing Cloud Backup Best Practices?

Tags: marketing-cloud, backup

Apologies if this has been asked before but I haven't been able to find a clear answer.

What are best practices for backing up SFMC? Not just the data but if someone were to mistakenly delete a journey or an automation, is there

Comment: As far as I know we cannot DELETE a Journey! only we can Stop it!....

Comment: Yes we can delete a Journey :) Its easy and doable through the UI. Check out this article: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=mc_jb_delete_journey.htm